# how to sort categories as they are shown in admin?

Tags: frontend

Here is the code:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(3);
$subCats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId())->getChildren();
$subCatIds = explode(',',$subCats);
$currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
```

Please advice, thx!

Answer (score 24):

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(3);
$children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
$children->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', $category->getId())
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)//get only active categories if you want
        ->addAttributeToSort('position');//sort by position

foreach ($children as $child){
    //do something with $child
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the snippet, but i want to stick to my code as it is already applied in the template. How can we add this sort attribute into the `$subCats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId())->getChildren();` ? thx!

Comment: You can replace `getChildren()` with `getChildrenCategories()` and you should have them sorted. But still you get the category objects not the ids. If you need the ids you can loop through the child categories and concatenate their ids. I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: ^^ I wish it was more clearly documented somewhere that `getChildren()` returns unsorted ID's, and `getChildrenCategories()` returns sorted objects.

This cleared up everything for me, the [magento docs themselves](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Catalog/Mage_Catalog_Model_Category.html#getChildren) as of now do not make this clear.

Comment: pretty sure getChildrenCategories doesn't work with Flat Categories

Comment: Need the same code for magento 2.

Answer (score 7):

You could try changing your code to use a nice mix of getChilderCategories() and the toArray function.

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(3);
$subCats = $category->getChildrenCategories();
$subCatIds = $subCats->toArray(array('entity_id'));
```

The getChildrenCategories function will give you a collection in the same order as the admin section and then by calling toArray and only asking for the entit_id attribute you will have an array of category ids

```
array(3) {
    [10]=> array(1) {
         ["entity_id"]=> string(2) "10"
    }
    [13]=> array(1) {
        ["entity_id"]=> string(2) "13"
    }
    [18]=> array(1) {
        ["entity_id"]=> string(2) "18"
    }
}
```